# Using htmlspecialchars at login and register

Tags: php

I am trying to protect my website from xss attacks and I use htmlspecialchars and mysqli_real_escape_string for this.

Now I am trying to let a user login and register, while he can still use signs like < or >.

I am using the following code for the username:
By signup:

```
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['username']);
    $username = strtolower($username);
    $username = htmlspecialchars($username);
```

And for login:

```
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['username']);
    $username = strtolower($username);
    $username = htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($username));
    echo "Username: $username<br>";
```

When I use a basic alert script at sign up for username, the username gets encrypted by htmlspecialchars and I see this in the database:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(\'2\')&lt;/script&gt;
```

When I try to login it says "Password or Username incorrect!",
but the echo at login exactly matches the username in the database.

First I only used one htmlspecialchars at login, but then it would just echo the username and it wouldn't change anything and I couldn't login.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You don't need `mysqli_real_escape_string` to avoid xss, this is (a bad way) to prevent SQL injections (prefer using prepared statements)

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is only useful if you plan on displaying the string or outputting it the html. There really isnt a use case for it to be in play to validate a string.

Answer (score 1):

Do not save the "HTML encoded" username in the database. The username should be as it is be saved in the database since that **is** the username the user wants to use. You also use this value to compare for the login with a [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) like `... WHERE username=?`. Having to work with `htmlspecialchars` and `html_decode()` for login/registration/lookup/compare purposes all the time will get you a headache.

When you use the username value from the database and want to output it at the medium of your choice you use the escape mechanism of the medium of your choice. As an example, for  output the value in HTML you use functions like `htmlspecialchars()`. This means that when the user registers with a username `iluvu<3` you store this value as such in the database (MySQL has not a problem with the `<` character), but for displaying purposes in HTML you use something like:

```
echo "Username: ".htmlspecialchars($username)."</br>";
```